# Deleting a message from pubnub history

Tags: android

I want to delete the message from history in Pubnub and I am using this code

```
 AppController.pubNub.deleteMessages()
    .channels(Arrays.asList(Constants.channelAtLogin+chat_user_id))
    .start(result.getMessages().get(i).getTimetoken())
    .end(result.getMessages().get(i).getTimetoken())
    .async(new PNCallback<PNDeleteMessagesResult>() {
           @Override
             public void onResponse(PNDeleteMessagesResult result, PNStatus status) {
               Log.d("delete_message",result.toString());                                     
             }
     });
```

But message is not deleted . Please help.

Comment: did you get any exception?

Comment: @AshishKudale No I didn't get any exception. But didn't get the result also. Messages are not deleted

Comment: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/message-update-delete refer this link it may help you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to show the result variable from your call which shouldn't give any result. The proper way to check if you're getting an error is to log the status. In other words, the code you're using above in essence is the correct code and is the one supported by PubNub.

```
pubnub.deleteMessages()
    .channels(Arrays.asList("channel_1", "channel_2"))
    .start(1460693607379L)
    .end(1460893617271L)
    .async(new PNCallback<PNDeleteMessagesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(PNDeleteMessagesResult result, PNStatus status) {
            // The deleteMessages() method does not return actionable data, be sure to check the status
            // object on the outcome of the operation by checking the status.isError().
            Log.d("Message_Deleted", status.isError().toString());  

        }
    });
```

If it isn't working the next step is to verify the data from the variables you are passing in.